# Add transition page by <div id="blablabla"> with tag <a href="#blablabla"">

Tags: html, css

Sorry for my english,

please help, how to add page transition, like a slide up or else whatever transition from other , by  .

something like this.

```
<div id="bla1" class="whatever">I am right page</div>
<div id="bla2">Behind right page</div>
```

And then i want to call with link id.

`<a href="#bla2'>I came from left side link</a>`

thank you before.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

you mad "' this mistake...

```
<a href="#bla2">I came from left side link</a>
```